# Been vs gone in present perfect negative sentences

Tags: present-perfect, been-vs-gone

Is it more correct to say "They haven't gone to the beach, they are still at home" (using gone as past participle)or "They haven't been to the beach, they are still at home (using been)?

Comment: Your second example looks slightly odd to me without the adverbial qualifier: *They haven't been to the beach **yet**, they are still at home.* But I'd still use ***gone*** (which always implies "not here") rather than ***been*** (which could also be used in "went somewhere else, but is now back here" contexts).

Comment: They are both 100% grammatical, i.e. correct.

Answer (score 3):

'To have been to [a place]' usually implies 'gone there and come back', so in the context you refer to, *gone* would be the appropriate choice.

> Have you ever been to (visited) Paris?
>
> I haven't been to the seaside since I visited Brighton in 2015.

Answer (score 0):

The definitive phrase in OP's example sentence is *still at home*, which means they have not left the house *yet*.

In OP's dramatic context:

They haven't gone to (i.e. departed for) the beach, and they certainly haven't  been to (i.e. visited and returned from, or visited and left) the beach.

Comment: been to is not always "go and return". It's **the** OP, afaic.

Comment: True, not always "visited and returned from", but visited and left, either for home or  to go to another destination. "They've been to London and now they're off to Edinburgh".

Comment: See my last comment under my answer. It is not worth arguing about.

Comment: The OP wanted to know if the sentences were grammatical or not. They both are.

Comment: @Lambie: OP asked  "which is more correct...?" not whether they were both grammatical.

Comment: Who would doubt that to say correct in this context is not the same as grammatical? That is really nitpicking.

Comment: @Lambie  You're focusing on the wrong word.  Not "correct" but "more" tells us that OP is interested in something other than mere grammaticality.

Comment: And one is not more correct (aka grammatical) than the other. For me, if something is incorrect, it can't be grammatical.

Answer (score -1):

They haven't gone to the beach. [that is not the place they went]. To *go somewhere*: I went to the beach yesterday. I've been there several times this month.

They *haven't been* to the beach. They've been to the pool this week. [same as gone to the beach, gone to the pool]

In any case, both those sentences are **grammatically correct**.

*I've been to* and *I've gone to* usually mean the same thing in the present perfect. However, be careful because this use of the verb *be* is not used in the simple present/present continuous.

**I go** [or any other tense] to the beach everyday. [good]
NOT: **I am or was to** the beach everyday.[buzzer]

The verb **be** + to a place has to be

The fact the verbs are negative is irrelevant here. They could be negative or interrogative.

In **some cases, not all** *been to* implies go and return but not always.

Comment: _I've been to and I've gone to mean the same thing in the present perfect._ I disagree. If you have been to a place, you have visited it in the past. If you have gone to a place, you are still there.

Comment: @KateBunting **They've gone to beach many times this month**. To go somewhere does not mean you are still there...

Comment: **In the context given by the OP**, I still maintain that 'gone' would be the appropriate choice.

Comment: "But John, they haven't been to the beach at all. They're still at home."

Comment: Why are you holding your jaw like that?  Idiomatic: I've been to the dentist.  Not quite idiomatic: I've gone to the dentist.

Comment: @Lambie: You're ignoring OP's phrase "still at home".  Why are you answering as though OP's example sentences put the word **beach** in italics? ["that is not the place they went"]

Comment: @TimR For pete's sake, can we just not do this? I did not put beach in italics. That is not the place they went because the sentence is negative and I was giving its meaning.

Comment: Do what, @Lambie?  Question the relevance of your answer to the question as asked?  Your answer implies that they went *somewhere*, but they have not left the house.

Comment: been to does not always mean go and return. I've been to the beach many times this year. is exactly the same as I've gone to the beach many times this year. Presumably, when you go to the beach, you also return from it. There are times it can be go and return, I'll concede that. But **not always**.

Comment: It doesn't in precisely those cases where any present perfect loses its special "perfect" semantics - where it is presented as one of a series or potential series over a period extending up to the present. eg "I've seen them many times".

Comment: @ColinFine That's sounding above my pay grade. :) But doesn't "I've been there many times." boil down practically to the same as "I've gone there many times."? The going is not like you go there and stay there. :) I think that pragmatically they mean the same thing in most cases. Not sure that "I've seen them many times" loses any "perfect semantics". Au contraire...